# SQL Server Management Studio Sorting Data in Results Pane

Tags: sql-server-2008, resultset

Is it possible to sort data in results pane (after query is executed) in Microsoft Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3):

No.   Best you can do is copy the data to Excel and then you can sort it as desired.

In the results pane, you're stuck with the order you asked for in the query.

Comment: why in 2023 SSMS does not have this feature?